# error:too many words `` in cat

Tags: csh, process-substitution

I have a csv file that auto-generate with filename format yy-mm-dd_h. The csv file content:

```
Status  Filename
1       1A-W02_ws_r0_apr13_15_44.stdf
1       2A-W04_ws_r1_apr12_10_30.stdf
1       1A-W13_ws_r0_apr01_19_04.stdf
```

The csv file will generate if I run this script. I must use C shell script to make an array for status and filename. Current code is:

```
set status = (`cat *`date +%F_%H`.csv | cut -d ',' -f1 | grep -v Status`)
```

I'm using  `date +%F_%H`  to reduce the possibility of error if there are 2 csv files (just in case the csv file not been deleted after script job done).
I faced the error

> too many words ``

when executing the script, but if I'm not using the date, the script can run normal. What's going wrong with the code?

Comment: you are embedding backticks incorrectly.

Comment: where should i put the bacticks?

Comment: You need to escape embedded backticks `\`cat *\\`date +%F_%H\\`.csv\``

Comment: @123 Yes, I didn't notice `csh`

Comment: like this `(`cat *\`date +%F_15`.csv` | cut -d ',' -f1 | grep -v Status`)` am i doing wrong? i got error unmatched `

Comment: i got error unmatched ` .. `cat *\`date +%F_15 \`.csv | cut -d ',' -f1 | grep -v Status`

Comment: theres a backslah (\) before the single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested command substitution will not work in `csh`. Declare the pattern as a variable and then construct your array using the variable.

```
set pattern = `date +%F_%H`
set status = ( `cut -d, -f1 <*$pattern.csv | grep -v Status` )
```